# How to update composable state from outside?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For example it working with state{} within composable function.

```
@Composable
fun CounterButton(text: String) {
    val count = state { 0 }

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        onClick = { count.value++ }) {
        Text(text = "$text ${count.value}")
    }
}
```

But how to update value outside of composable function?
I found a mutableStateOf() function and MutableState interface which can be created outside composable function, but no effect after value update.

Not working example of my attempts:

```
private val timerState = mutableStateOf("no value", StructurallyEqual)

@Composable
private fun TimerUi() {
    Button(onClick = presenter::onTimerButtonClick) {
        Text(text = "Timer Button")
    }
    Text(text = timerState.value)
}

override fun updateTime(time: String) {
    timerState.value = time
}
```

Compose version is 0.1.0-dev14

Comment: For now, try `FrameManager.framed { timerState.value = time }`. Eventually, [that will no longer be needed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1326201), but probably not until `dev15` or later.

Comment: @CommonsWare no effect: 
override fun updateTime(time: String) = FrameManager.framed { timerState.value = time }

Comment: No effect after update to 0.1.0-dev15

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108186/1971461

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by exposing the state through a parameter of the controlled composable function and instantiate it externally from the controlling composable.

Instead of:

```
@Composable
fun CounterButton(text: String) {
     val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
     //....
 }
```

You can do something like:

```
@Composable
fun screen() {

    val counter = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        CounterButton(
            text = "Click count:",
            count = counter.value,
            updateCount = { newCount ->
                counter.value = newCount
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CounterButton(text: String, count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = { updateCount(count+1) }) {
        Text(text = "$text ${count}")
    }
}
```

In this way you can make internal state controllable by the function that called it.
It is called **state hoisting**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not what I asked about. I need to update value from non composable function

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, this really helps. Bue how to utilize this if we want to send more than 1 value. Like here you are sending an updated "count" value. What if I have say "count" and "total", i.e. 2 items to be sent?