# Update State outside the composable function. (Jetpack compose)

Tags: kotlin, redux, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I am trying to implement redux with Jetpack compose. The scenario looks like this:

I have a list view where I need to show data, in composable function.

```
    @Composable
    fun CreateListView(text: String) {
     val listdata = state { store.state }

        LazyColumn {
         //some listview code here
        }
    }
```

above, I want to use the data that I got from the redux store. but the store. The subscription method is standalone, and outside the composable. where, though I am able to update the state through new data, but the changes are not reflecting back to composable listview:

```
    // activity page outside composable
    private fun storeSubscription(){
        viewModel.storeSubscription = store.subscribe {

            when (store.state) {
                store.state = // list data from some source
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to update the composable, like above, from outside the function, and without sending any parameter? Since the redux store is a global one, so it should work I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like,

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> Store<T>.asState(): State<T> {
   val result = remember { mutableStateOf(store.state) }
   DisposableEffect {
       val unsubscribe = store.subscribe {
           result.value = store.state
       }
       onDispose { unsubscribe() }
   }
   return result
}

@Composable
fun CreateListView(text: String) {
    val listdata by store.asState()

    LazyColumn {
     //some listview code here
    }
}
```

The exact code might differ as I don't know what redux implementation you are using.

This creates an observable state object that will be updated whenever the lambda passed to `subscribe` is called. Also, it will automatically unsubscribe when `CreateListView` is no longer part of the composition.

Answer (score 10):

You can use MutableLiveData outside of composable function. Use observeAsState() in composable to recompose when data changes.

```
private val myLive = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun nonComposableScope(){
  myLive.postValue("hello")
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(textLive:LiveData<String>){
  val text: String? by textLive.observeAsState()
  // use text here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You could simply use a lambda like so:**

(An example from an app I am working on.)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun RumbleSearchResult(rumbleSearchResult: RumbleSearchResult, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    ListItem(
        headlineText = {
            rumbleSearchResult.title?.let { title ->
                Text(title)
            }
        },

        supportingText = {
            rumbleSearchResult.channel.let { creator ->
                val text = when {
                    rumbleSearchResult.views > 0 -> {
                        "${creator.name}, ${rumbleSearchResult.views} views"
                    }

                    else -> {
                        creator.name ?: ""
                    }
                }

                Row {
                    Text(text)

                    if (creator.isVerified) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_verified_24),
                            tint = Color.Cyan,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.mainActivity_verified_content_description)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        leadingContent = {
            AsyncImage(
                rumbleSearchResult.thumbnailSrc,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp, 100.dp)
            )
        },

        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            onClick.invoke()
        }
    )
    Divider()
}
```

Main composable:

```
LazyColumn {
    items(viewModel.searchResults) {
        RumbleSearchResult(rumbleSearchResult = it) {
            openDialog = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the state hosting pattern
From [Android Domcumentaiton](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

> Key Term: State hoisting is a pattern of moving state up the tree to
> make a component stateless.
>
> When applied to composables, this often means introducing two
> parameters to the composable:
>
> value: T: the current value to display. onValueChange: (T) -> Unit: an
> event that requests the value to change where T is the proposed new
> value.

So in your case you will save the state in the upper Composable that needs to access it, and pass the value of the state and a lambda function to change it to the other Composable, you can learn more from the Official Documentation.

Comment: and what if my store subscription method is not in any composable method? @david-ibrahim

Comment: you can pass store subscription as a lambda to your composable

Comment: not yet, i don't want to pass the store subscription as a parameter.